# Messages not reaching handler while using WebSocket and nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, nestjs, ws

I am trying to implement `WebSocket` into `nestjs` app and I have problems with messages not reaching my handler in `nestjs`.

I am able to connect both ends and send message from `nestjs` to `client` but not the other way.

this is my `nestjs` code: (please note that i am not using `socket.io` i am implementing `ws` as `WebSocket`

```
import {
    OnGatewayInit,
    WebSocketGateway,
    WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@WebSocketGateway(5015)
export class ExportFeedsGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
    @WebSocketServer() wss: any;

    private logger: Logger = new Logger('ExportFeedsGateway');

    afterInit(server: any): any {
        this.logger.log('Export Feeds Initialized');
    }

    handleConnection(client) {
        client.send('message from server'); // this message is properly send and read on the client side
    }

    handleMessage(message) {
        console.log('message', message); // this is never logged in nest
    }
}
```

and some client code:

```
const WebSocket = require( 'ws');

    ...

        this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5015');
        this.ws.on('open', () => {
            this.ws.send('message from client') // this message never reaches server
        });

    ...
```

Question is what is the problem with `nestjs` messages handler that it doesnt pick up messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `@SubscribeMessage('message')` that you'll need for Nest to register the handler to the websocket server. `handleConnection` is a bit of a special case method [as defined inthe lifecycle methods](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways#lifecycle-hooks). Also, when sending the message from the `ws` library, use the form: `ws.send('{"event": "message", "data": whateverDataObjectYouWant }', callback)`. This way, Nest can parse the event and properly route it